# PostgreSQL - Dynamic addition of large no of columns

Tags: postgresql, multiple-columns, alter-table, query-performance

Assume I have a table named `tracker` with columns `(issue_id,ingest_date,verb,priority)`

I would like to add 50 columns to this table.

Columns being `(string_ch_01,string_ch_02,.....,string_ch_50)` of datatype `varchar`.

Is there any better way to add columns with single procedure rather than executing the following alter command 50 times?

`ALTER TABLE tracker ADD COLUMN string_ch_01 varchar(1020);`

Comment: The real question is: why do you think you need those 50 columns? What is the problem you are trying to solve? Sequentially numbered columns very often indicate a wrong (de-normalized) database design. And this case does sound as if you really just need a one-to-many relationship

Comment: I am creating 50 columns because my tool gives privilege to create his/her own set of fields.

Am okay with having (de-normalized) database design as it is a better way for data mining.

Note: I need only one to one relationship.

Comment: A `hstore` column might be a better choice for this.

Comment: Thank you. However my postgre version( 8.0 ) doesn't support it. 'hstore' is available only from version 9.1. Could you please help me with a procedure(PL/SQL procedure) to achieve it?

Comment: Instead of trying to use that outdated and unsupported version, you should upgrade to a version that is still maintained **now** (e.g. 9.4). (btw: it's Postgres, not Postgre)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a better way is to issue a single ALTER TABLE with all the columns at once:

```
ALTER TABLE tracker
   ADD COLUMN string_ch_01 varchar(1020),
   ADD COLUMN string_ch_02 varchar(1020),
   ...
   ADD COLUMN string_ch_50 varchar(1020)
;
```

It's especially better when there are DEFAULT non-null clauses for the new columns, since each of them would rewrite the entire table, as opposed to rewriting it only once if they're grouped in a single ALTER TABLE.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I am currently using Postgre version 8.0. Hence, the above code shows me syntax error.